# Diferencia entre Rutas

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, rutas

cual es la diferencia que las rutas las coloque manual o cree la ruta que menciona laravel?, me explico:

si yo creo mis rutas como por ejemplo:

```
Route::post ('/create', 'EjemploController@create');
Route::get('edit/{id}', 'EjemploController@edit')->name('editar');
```

o creo la funcion de resource así:

```
Route::resource('/ejemplo','ejemploController');
```

¿Cuál es la diferencia?

Comment: Como tengo entendido `Route::resource('/ejemplo','ejemploController');`te da por default todos los recursos del controlador `Edit, update, create, index, etc`y del otro modo es practicamente lo mismo, la ventaja creo que de este ultimo que menciono es que puedes darles un "name" igual puedes verlo en la consola con el comando `php artisan r:l`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La diferencia es que de la primera forma defines los métodos y acciones que deseas, y con el método resource te crea las siete acciones típicas, que son: index (listado), create (formulario de creación), store (almacenar nuevo), show (mostrar registro), edit (formulario de edición), update (actualizar registro), destroy (borrar).

Aquí el ejemplo de la generación con resource para UserController:

```
|        | POST      | usuario                | usuario.store       | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@store                              | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | usuario                | usuario.index       | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@index                              | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | usuario/create         | usuario.create      | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@create                             | web          |
|        | DELETE    | usuario/{usuario}      | usuario.destroy     | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@destroy                            | web          |
|        | PUT|PATCH | usuario/{usuario}      | usuario.update      | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@update                             | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | usuario/{usuario}      | usuario.show        | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@show                               | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | usuario/{usuario}/edit | usuario.edit        | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@edit                               | web          |
```

Es de aclarar que con el método except() se puede evitar la creación de alguna acción que no se necesite:

```
Route::resource('usuario', 'UserController')->except(['show']);
```

---

Como siempre, todo está en la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: Muchas Gracias amigo! quede mas claro, estaba viendo la documentacion pero aun asi no lo entendia jaja, gracias por tu tiempo!

Answer (score 3):

La diferencia es que con el método resource se te crea automáticamente 7 rutas para los 7 métodos rest.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mientras que cómo tu las haces manualmente tendrías que hacerlo una por una.

Saludos. Puedes verificar esto ejecutando el comando: php artisan r:l y verás que es lo mismo.